# Function Call in DLL not working as expected (QueueUserAPC)

Tags: dll, queue, c++14, apc

I do understand what an APC is, how it works, It works fine in exe. though it 's not working in dll once I copy the whole code into dll. 
Here is the code snippet below.

```
...
typedef struct
{
    LPCSTR lpCmdLine;
    UINT   uCmdShow;
}test;

typedef UINT(WINAPI *WINEXEC)(LPCSTR, UINT);

HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll");
    LPVOID pFunc1 = GetProcAddress(hModule, "WinExec");
    ((WINEXEC)pFunc1)("notepad.exe", SW_SHOW);
    test a = { "notepad.exe", SW_SHOW };
...
hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, TID);
QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)pFunc1, hThread , (ULONG_PTR)&a);

..
```

please help me to resolve this issue. 
Looking forward to hearing back from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Rose
It seems APC is pretty obvious at the moment, let me check in the evening when I back from work.
Have you ever checked the address of the functions you used for the importing in dll vs exe? 
Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I'll be waiting.